# Spring Rest Controllers global security filter

Tags: authentication, spring-mvc, bearer-token

I have a REST application with Spring MVC, I would like to set a custom global filter to validate a bearer-token in HTTP request.

How can I write a common authentication filter valid for all controllers and all methods?
It should be able to access the HTTP request data.

I don't want to use Spring security component.

Comment: Don't write your own, use Spring Security, why yours will always be a half arsed, badly implemented version of what is available in the open source space. So use Spring Security, Apache Shiro or whatever is pre-build.

Comment: Yes sure, but my software is so bad that it had never been affected by a 0-day vulnerabilities and it is unknown to metasploit fw and company.

Comment: Regardless never try to reinvent the wheel, especially the security wheel. Use proven solutions like Spring Security and Apache Shiro for that.